# Adding class to HTML element ID from a PHP script

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to hack a contact form I downloaded (https://css-tricks.com/examples/NiceSimpleContactForm2/) ... I have rewritten the HTML and CSS to make it more modular, but I want to adapt the PHP contact engine document - particularly this bit:

```
// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
```

This loads a thank you page, which is a bit clunky. I want to use some CSS classes to display a message in the HTML that will indicate success or failure. Trouble is, I know nothing about PHP, or how I would go about targeting an HTML element ID and adding a class to it from the PHP script.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: *I know nothing about PHP*... Well then I'd recommend reading up on the basics, and understanding how it interacts with HTML content.

Comment: Personally... I'd run it through AJAX and have it run on the same page with no loading..

Comment: Thanks @GAntoine - I would never have thought of that. If I had the time to read up on it I would ... I don't, therefore I decided to consult the experts. Who knew I would get such sage advice.

Comment: Thanks for looking @Option, but I'm really only interested in trying to modify what I have.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be snarky Gareth, sorry if I came off that way. We, as developers, spend a lot of time reading and learning, to understand the tools we use. My employer doesn't have the time to do that, so he hired me to do it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of refreshing same page, you should redirect to the respective pages based on your `$success` variable.

```
// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  header('Location: contactthanks.php');
}
else{
  header('Location: error.htm');
}
```

or, simply somewhere in the body tag of your contact form page.

```
<?php if ($success): ?>
    <div class="success">Thanks!</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="error">Error!</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to avoid redirecting altogether. I want to change the CSS class of an element in my original HTML page to indicate success or failure.

Comment: Then check out the second code example in that answer - notice how it adds a _div_ element with a unique _class_ attribute. Then you could utilize those class names in CSS.

Comment: Will code in the HTML/PHP document work if the sendform is a separate document?